# Language packs for german (DE and AT)

Tags: magento-1.9, localisation, language, language-package

Since I cannot find any documentation or references to good / complete translations. I decided to ask this on Stackexchange. Is there any descent listing? And what would you use for the above locales? (first time I need to implement them and my German is not that imba)

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the installations of Magento DE (http://de.nr-apps.com/store/magento-de.html) or Mangeto AT (http://de.nr-apps.com/store/magento-at.html?utm_source=product.related&utm_campaign=Magento+AT).

There are several useful settings and extension installed especially for the german or austrian market.

Comment: The german language pack is here: http://de.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/locale-mage-community-de-de.html

Comment: Thanks,  does this need alot of editing / are there errors?

Comment: No. Could you please set this as answered if I could help you :-)